# Getting an image that is inside a table to have no space

Tags: html, css

I have a table that contains another table which holds and image. The first table has a set width and height but when I add an image inside the second table more space is added at the top and bottom. I tried to have 0 padding and margin but that doesn't work.

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/aphz3hga/

```
  <body style="background-color:##EEEEEE;">
    <table class="body" style="margin:0 auto;">
      <tr>
        <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">

         <center>

          <!-- Email Content -->
            <table style="background-color:#850038; width:600px; height:245px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table style="margin:0 auto;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yNPG35t.png">
                                </td>   
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>



          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, edit your fiddle properly. Put the mouse cursor inside HTML area, press Enter key, and then edit it according to showed messages: http://imgur.com/vPe2XbJ

Comment: also keep in mind that the `<center>` tag is deprecated. use CSS to center stuff instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply these styles:

By default tables(cells) have separate borders by 2 px. `border-collapse: collapse;` removes this space.

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Again, cells have 1px padding. We remove that too.

```
table td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

And, `img` elements are inline elements and they have some space (margin or padding) which doesn't show in DevTools. Setting the image's display to block solves that.

```
img {
  display: block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aphz3hga/3/)